# Can correlation between fit parameters cause this function to not fit data?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, astronomy, lmfit

```
from lmfit import Model

def PSF_fit(r,beta,alpha):
R=((beta-1)/(3.14*alpha*alpha))*((1+ (r / alpha)**2)**(-beta))
return R

moffat = Model(PSF_fit)

print(f'parameter names: {moffat.param_names}')
print(f'independent variables: {moffat.independent_vars}')

params = moffat.make_params(beta=2.85,alpha=1.5)

result = moffat.fit(Intensity, params,r=r)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
plt.plot(r,Intensity, 'bo')

plt.plot(r, result.init_fit, '--', label='initial fit')
plt.plot(r, result.best_fit, '-', label='best fit')
plt.xlabel('Radius(pixels)')
plt.ylabel('Saturation corrected profile')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Circular Moffat Fit')
plt.show()
```

I was trying to fit the above mentioned circular moffat function to a Flux profile. But it doesn't seem to fit. My fit report is as follows:

```
parameter names: ['beta', 'alpha']
independent variables: ['r']
[[Model]]
Model(PSF_fit)
[[Fit Statistics]]
# fitting method   = leastsq
# function evals   = 248
# data points      = 28
# variables        = 2
chi-square         = 127948.959
reduced chi-square = 4921.11382
Akaike info crit   = 239.961102
Bayesian info crit = 242.625511
[[Variables]]
beta:   18.2260915 +/- 1845366.32 (10124860.41%) (init = 2.85)
alpha:  9.61025099 +/- 553166.734 (5756007.15%) (init = 1.429321)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
C(beta, alpha) = 0.999
```

Can the correlation between alpha and beta be causing this?

This is the fit result. [Fit result for circular Moffat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFGSL.png)

Comment: Is your function implemented correctly and you have provided sensible initial values? I am surprised that your initial guess does not show the behaviour of the data at all.

Comment: Try providing better starting parameters. Your plot shows the initial and final fit to be the same, while there have at least been 248 function evaluations. This more indicates bad starting values.

Comment: The function has been implemented correctly, I checked this by manually evaluating  for a some random values and then calling the function. The initial values may be incorrect ( mostly because of units) . I will check it.

Comment: Your fitting function is missing a normalization/amplitude parameter. Add that extra parameter, and things may work a lot better. (For example, try plotting your current initial function by itself: it has far too low values.)